# The way for not disabling the firewall in windows

Tags: windows, firewalls

I have been doing this for about a year without knowing the purposes of disabling. Whenever i tried to ping/connected to my host VM via guest VM, i have to disable my host VM's firewall, but does it make my Host VM in harmfull situation ? i mean it's not safe anymore. Well i it's not a problem if it a VM, but how about in the actual machine ?

Is there a way so i didn't have to disabled my windows's firewall and my computer still secured ?

Comment: you can simply create firewall rules to allow the guest VM to ping

Comment: it might be helpful for us to know if you understand what a firewall does - do you?